# Kotlin Jacoco coverage not showing for static methods (companion) in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, code-coverage, jacoco

I implemented Jacoco in my Android project using the following tutorial https://proandroiddev.com/unified-code-coverage-for-android-revisited-44789c9b722f to cater for test coverage in the kotlin classes.

For some unknown reason, it's not reporting coverage for static methods declared under the Companion block.

```
class Meh {
    companion object {
     fun test () {
     // logic to test
     }
}
```

However if I convert the class to an instance rather than a singleton that I am able to see the coverage completely fine.

Has anyone came across this problem ? and what did you do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> following tutorial https://proandroiddev.com/unified-code-coverage-for-android-revisited-44789c9b722f

after cloning of example from the same tutorial in its state as of today ([HEAD commit](https://github.com/rafaeltoledo/unified-code-coverage-android/tree/57ebcffedeaf9063cd2caca35bcbe1333720e81e))

```
git clone https://github.com/rafaeltoledo/unified-code-coverage-android.git
cd unified-code-coverage-android
git checkout kotlin-coverage
```

addition of companion object into `MainActivity`

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

+    companion object {
+      fun executed() {
+      }
+
+      fun notExecuted() {
+      }
+    }
+
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

+        executed()
```

start of virtual device `Pixel XL` with API `28` and target `Android 9.0 (Google APIs)` in freshly downloaded `Android Studio 3.2.1`

and execution of

```
./gradlew jacocoTestReport
```

following report is produced in directory `app/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/` as expected

[image]

[image]

Given the amount of factors that influence result (such as versions of all involved components - Android SDK, Device, Kotlin compiler, Gradle, JaCoCo, etc, etc), attempts to guess what is different in your case are IMO counterproductive, and so that the best advice - is to perform very careful comparison of differences between your setup and above example.

---

#### Update

As was figured out during comparison by @HeWhoProtects , problem was in

> exclusion of `**/*$*`

that refers to exclusion of class files from analysis. Single source file can compile into multiple class files, e.g. in case of nested classes in Java and exactly in case of companion in Kotlin and in both cases name of class and class file will contain `$`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the the cause of the problem but not sure why it caused it yet, my excludes rules includes more rules than the one in the tutorial above, in different jacoco tutorial for ignoring autogenerated files, it was suggested to include `'**/*$*'` as rule, as soon as I removed it, it showed coverage for static methods in kotlin.

My understanding of Jacoco that these rules ignore files and will not show it in the report, and before I made the change, it was showing that this class is covered in the test coverage.... is it weird or am I missing a fundamental thing about how kotlin generates methods or how jacoco excludes rules work ?

Anyway I hope this helps..

Comment: You're probably referring to exclusion and inclusion of **class** files or classes, this is not the same as **source** files - single source file can compile into multiple class files, e.g. in case of nested classes in Java and exactly in case of companion in Kotlin and in both cases name of class and class file will contain `$`.

Comment: Thanks! It does work! In my case it was `companion` being ignored